# Google Maps API v3 disabling markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been working on a Google Maps project that allows you to draw and save a boundary (polygon) onto a map. This is then saved to a database and the page refreshes and pulls back the information onto the map.

I found the code below from another users post and adapted it to my needs which works perfectly until you draw the polygon on from the database.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {
    polygon.setEditable(true);
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'set_at', function () {
        document.getElementById("coordsField").value = updateArray(polygon);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon.getPath(), 'insert_at', function () {
        document.getElementById("coordsField").value = updateArray(polygon);
    });
});
```

The code creates a listener that waits for the polygon to be complete. It then sets the polygon to be editable and creates two more listeners. The first waits for a current point to be updated and the second waits for a new point to be created, both of them then update an array with all of the points and saves this to a hidden field when triggered.

This code works perfectly for creating a new polygon however when a polygon is created from the database this is another story. As the listener waits for a polygon to be complete it never triggers as it is actioned automatically. I have attempted to remove the wrapper:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(drawingManager, 'polygoncomplete', function(polygon) {}
```

and add the update listeners however I get an error for 'polygon is undefined'. Would somebody be able to explain how to resolve this?

Comment: How do you create a polygon from the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

trigger the polygoncomplete-event for the drawingManager and pass the automatically created polygon-instance as argument to the callback(3rd argument of `trigger`):

```
polygonInstance = new google.maps.Polygon(/*options*/);

google.maps.event.trigger(drawingManager, 
                         'polygoncomplete',
                          polygonInstance);
```